# Change a configuration property for Teamcity

Tags: c++, teamcity

I am fairly new to teamcity 7.1, but I installed teamcity and then found that I needed to install a new version of Windows SDK from 6.0A to 7.1 due to the ldap.h file. When I run the msbuild for our C++ application I get the ldap not found error.

I believe this is related to needing the newer SDK. Anyway I notice on the Agent properties of 
WindowsSDKv6.0A      v6.0A
WindowsSDKv6.0A_Path     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A

Should I just add the 7.1 ? or is there a way to replace this configuration property all together?

The buildAgent.properties file does not list any of the configuration properties that exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing configuration properties are detected automatically by Teamcity agent.

According to Teamcity's document [PredefinedBuildParameters-AgentProperties](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-AgentProperties):

> TeamCity automatically detects a number of applications including the
>   presence of .NET Framework, Visual Studio and adds the corresponding
>   system properties and environment variables

And in table of the same page, it shows:

> **WindowsSDK** This property is defined if the corresponding
>   version of Windows SDK is installed. (Supported versions are 6.0,
>   6.0A, 7.0, 7.0A, 7.1)

So try to restart Teamcity agent to see if it can pick up the newly installed SDK automatically.

If it can't, try to add the 7.1 properties in the **buildAgent.properties** file, and then restart the build agent.

And to tell msbuild to use the correct SDK:

> - Go to "**Start**" menu and search "**Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt**"
> - In the prompt, type "**cd setup**"
> - In the prompt, type "**WindowsSdkVer.exe -version:v7.1**"